# laravel created_at is not showing the correct value ie inside the database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, laravel-5.4

Hi i have a table named invoice and i am trying to search the pi created between specific date and all the operation is going in right direction and showing the correct result as i want but my **created_at** column is not showing the correct value it showing me today date instead of showing the database value.

my controller code

```
 public function search_pi1(Request $request){

            $from_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->from_date));
            $to_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->to_date));
            $q=$request->q;
            $pi=PI::where('created_at','>=',$from_date)->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)->where('company_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();

            $params=[
                'pi'=>$pi,
                'from_date'=>$request->from_date,
                'to_date'=>$request->to_date,
                'q'=>$q,
            ];
            return view('pi.search_pi1')->with($params);

    }
```

and my view code is

```
@if(sizeof($pi)>0)
               <div class="table-responsive">

                <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S.N.</th>
                        <th>Invoice No</th>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Source</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Dept</th>
                        <th>Creation Date</th>
                        <th>Created By</th>

                        <th colspan="2">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @php($i=1)
                      @foreach($pi as $enquiry)

                        <tr>
                        <td>{{$i++}}</td>
                         <td>{{$enquiry->invoiceNumber}}</td>
                        <td>{{$enquiry->company_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$enquiry->invoice_source}}</td>
                        <td>{{$enquiry->invoice_destination}}</td>
                        <td>{{$enquiry->dept}}</td>

                      <td>


                          {{ $enquiry->created_at }}

                      </td>
                      <td>{{$enquiry->created_by}}</td>
                      <td>   <form action="{{ route('pi.editPi')}}" method="post">

              <input type="text" name="pi_id" value="{{$enquiry->id}}"  style="display: none;">
                               <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                               <i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>  </button>


            </form></td>

                       <td><a href="" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="Delete"></i> </a></td>

                    </tr>
                      @endforeach





                    </tbody>
                </table>

</div>




            </div>        @else
            <br> <br> <br>
            <h4 style="color: red;text-align: center;">No Record Found</h4>
            @endif
```

when i search the pi created between 20-3-2018 to 22-03-2018 and it is showing me two record but the created at column is showing 22 Mar 2018 - 07:38:11     instead of showing the database actual value.

**1 35  The Manali Inn  Himachal Pradesh    Himachal Pradesh    Mr. Manoj Sharma Tel 123456987 22 Mar 2018 - 07:38:11   ADMIN

2   693 Venus Traders   Delhi   Andaman and Nicobar Island  Mr.Vinod Tel: 123456789 22 Mar 2018 - 07:38:11  ADMIN**

Below is my table data for this search

view format is [image]

db table record
[image]

i notice one more thing that if i change the system date then it showing the date which i set in the system not the database date anyone have the idea

PI Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PI extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'invoice';
    protected $fillable = ['invoiceNumber','eid','company_name','address','city','dept','form_type','security1','invoice_source','invoice_destination','invoice_type','tin_no','cust_order_no',];
     protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

}
```

Comment: can you please share table data

Comment: i have updated the table data in question

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct data from the request? $request->from_date should probably be $request->get('from_date'); You could also check how to use Carbon to handle dates for you

Comment: i have created two date picker for that from_date and to_date

Comment: the problem is not with date but in database the created_at value is different then showing me in view

Comment: The date which showing in view, is different because you have change the format of it

Comment: i have tried both before changing the format same result shown

Comment: can't understand your problem, please share table data with proper format

Comment: shared please read the question

Comment: @AnilKumarSahu , Try adding "created_at" into `protected $fillable` of your model (PI)

Comment: Your should change this code`PI::where('created_at','>=',$from_date)->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)` to become `PI::whereDate('created_at','>=',$from_date)->whereDate('created_at','<=',$to_date)`

Comment: When it's about date-time, use php [carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/).

Comment: do you override any date property in your `PI` model or basemodel?

Comment: no i have also add the PI model in question please check

Comment: try removing the`created_at` from dates array[testing option]

Comment: that i also tried but not getting the output i am wondering that first time in my life this type of error occur

Comment: if you dump the `$enquiry->created_at` in controller and in view what you get? `dd($enquiry->created_at)`

Comment: when i print_r($pi) then the created_at showing me database value right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167333/discussion-between-ab-in-and-anil-kumar-sahu).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to resolve this problem.

1. You can add the time along with Y-m-d.
   e.g.

   ```
    public function search_pi1(Request $request){

       $from_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->from_date)) . '00:00:00';
       $to_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->to_date)) . '23:59:59';
       $q=$request->q;
       $pi=PI::where('created_at','>=',$from_date)->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)->where('company_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();

       $params=[
           'pi'=>$pi,
           'from_date'=>$request->from_date,
           'to_date'=>$request->to_date,
           'q'=>$q,
       ];
       return view('pi.search_pi1')->with($params);

    }
   ```

But this will be a layman way to solve the problem.

2. You can update the where method with whereDate Method

   ```
    public function search_pi1(Request $request){

       $from_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->from_date));
       $to_date=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->to_date));
       $q=$request->q;
       $pi=PI::whereDate('created_at','>=',$from_date)->whereDate('created_at','<=',$to_date)->where('company_name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->get();

       $params=[
           'pi'=>$pi,
           'from_date'=>$request->from_date,
           'to_date'=>$request->to_date,
           'q'=>$q,
       ];
       return view('pi.search_pi1')->with($params);

    }
   ```

Please feel free to ask me further and in case you find something wrong please let me know.

Comment: both the condition have tried but not getting the exact output

Comment: Okay Please, can you share which laravel version are you using?

Comment: laravel-5.4 version

Comment: Okay thanks @AnilKumarSahu, After checking with this as I have run it in my system and its giving me correct results.

Comment: so did you have any solution for that